# What is the difference between subtyping and inheritance in OO programming?

Tags: oop, computer-science

I could not find the main difference. And I am very confused when we could use inheritance and when we can use subtyping. I found some definitions but they are not very clear.

What is the difference between subtyping and inheritance in object-oriented programming?

Comment: Where have you seen them being described as being different?

Comment: @JonSkeet - Are all the answers here wrong? :/

Comment: @Sipo: While not necessarily *wrong* as such, I think if the OP had included some context (4 years ago...) it would have made for a significantly better question.

Comment: @JonSkeet - So... Is there a difference? I came across this question just now...

Comment: @Sipo: I think they're used slightly inconsistently between languages, to be honest.

Answer (score 48):

In addition to the answers already given, here's a [link](http://www.cmi.ac.in/%7Emadhavan/courses/pl2006/lecturenotes/lecture-notes/node28.html) to an article I think is relevant.
Excerpts:

> In the object-oriented framework, inheritance is usually presented as a feature that goes hand in hand with subtyping when one organizes abstract datatypes in a hierarchy of classes. However, the two are orthogonal ideas.
>
> - Subtyping refers to compatibility of interfaces. A type `B` is a subtype of `A` if every function that can be invoked on an object of type `A` can also be invoked on an object of type `B`.
> - Inheritance refers to reuse of implementations. A type `B` inherits from another type `A` if some functions for `B` are written in terms of functions of `A`.
>
> However, subtyping and inheritance need not go hand in hand. Consider the data structure deque, a double-ended queue. A deque supports insertion and deletion at both ends, so it has four functions `insert-front`, `delete-front`, `insert-rear` and `delete-rear`. If we use just `insert-rear` and `delete-front` we get a normal queue. On the other hand, if we use just `insert-front` and `delete-front`, we get a stack. In other words, we can implement queues and stacks in terms of deques, so as datatypes, `Stack` and `Queue` inherit from `Deque`. On the other hand, neither `Stack` nor `Queue` are subtypes of `Deque` since they do not support all the functions provided by `Deque`. In fact, in this case, `Deque` is a subtype of both `Stack` and `Queue`!

I think that Java, C++, C# and their ilk have contributed to the confusion, as already noted, by the fact that they consolidate both ideas into a single class hierarchy. However, I think the example given above does justice to the ideas in a rather language-agnostic way. I'm sure others can give more examples.

Comment: That was a perfectly picked excerpt. Thank you for sharing helped cleared my doubts.

Answer (score 15):

A relative unfortunately died and left you his bookstore.

You can now read all the books there, sell them, you can look at his accounts, his customer list, etc. This is **inheritance** - you have everything the relative had. Inheritance is a form of code reuse.

You can also re-open the book store yourself, taking on all of the relative's roles and responsibilities, even though you add some changes of your own - this is **subtyping** - you are now a bookstore owner, just like your relative used to be.

Subtyping is a key component of OOP - you have an object of one type but which fulfills the interface of another type, so it can be used anywhere the other object could have been used.

In the languages you listed in your question - C++, Java and C# - the two are (almost) always used together, and thus the only way to inherit from something is to subtype it and vice versa. But other languages don't necessarily fuse the two concepts.

Answer (score 8):

Inheritance is about gaining attributes (and/or functionality) of super types. For example:

```
class Base {
    //interface with included definitions

}

class Derived inherits Base {
    //Add some additional functionality.
    //Reuse Base without having to explicitly forward
    //the functions in Base
}
```

Here, a `Derived` cannot be used where a `Base` is expected, but is able to act similarly to a `Base`, while adding behaviour or changing some aspect of `Base`s behaviour. Typically, `Base` would be a small helper class that provides both an interface and an implementation for some commonly desired functionality.

Subtype-polymorphism is about implementing an interface, and so being able to substitute different implementations of that interface at run-time:

```
class Interface {
    //some abstract interface, no definitions included
}

class Implementation implements Interface {
    //provide all the operations 
    //required by the interface
}
```

Here, an `Implementation` can be used wherever an `Interface` is required, and different implementations can be substituted at run-time. The purpose is to allow code that uses `Interface` to be more widely useful.

Your confusion is justified. Java, C#, and C++ all conflate these two ideas into a single class hierarchy. However, the two concepts are not identical, and there do exist languages which separate the two.

Comment: Can you list languages which separate the two ?

Comment: @letronje: Inheritance without subtyping is often implemented via a [mixin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixin) concept (but a mixin is often slightly less restricted than inheritance). For example, in D, you can write [template mixins](http://dlang.org/template-mixin.html), which are essentially a way to inject code and data into an arbitrary scope.

Answer (score 5):

If you inherit privately in C++, you get inheritance without subtyping. That is, given:

```cpp
class Derived : Base        // note the missing public before Base
```

You cannot write:

```cpp
Base * p = new Derived();   // type error
```

Because `Derived` is not a subtype of `Base`. You merely inherited the implementation, not the type.

Comment: Technically, you still get subtyping with private inheritance, it's just that the subtyping is private to the class...

Comment: If I change the inheritance to :
class Derived : public Base

can I write :
Base * p = new Derived();

Answer (score 1):

Subtyping doesn't have to be implemented via inheritance. Some subtyping that is not inheritance:

1. [Ocaml's variant](https://realworldocaml.org/v1/en/html/variants.html)
2. [Rust's lifetime anotation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.17.0/book/lifetimes.html)
3. [Clean's uniqueness types](http://www.eafit.edu.co/investigacion/grupos/logica-y-computacion/seminar/seminar/2014/clean-uniqueness-typing-slides.pdf)
4. Go's interface

Answer (score 1):

**in a simple word**: subtyping and inheritance both are polymorphism, (inheritance is a dynamic polymorphism - overriding). Actually, inheritance is subclassing, it means in inheritance there is no warranty to ensure capability of the subclass with the superclass (make sure subclass do not discard superclass behavior), but subtyping(such as implementing an interface and ... ), ensure the class does not discard the expected behavior.