# Inheritance vs. subtyping in TypeScript - a bug?

Tags: typescript, inheritance, subtyping

I code in TypeScript and it seems to allow to produce a non-type safe code. I'm using all the "strict" options I have found. The behaviour I notice is strictly against "Inheritance implies subtyping", as discussed for instance in:

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50729485/override-method-with-different-argument-types-in-extended-class-typescript](https://stackoverflow.com)

The code that raises no type errors is the following:

```
abstract class A {
    abstract do(x: number | string): number;
}

class B extends A {
    override do(x: number): number {
        return x;
    }
}

const a: A = new B();

const x: number = a.do("dupa");

console.log(x);
```

I would expect an error like

```
Error:(7, 14) TS2416: Property 'do' in type 'B' is not assignable to the same property in base type 'A'.
  Type '(x: number) => number' is not assignable to type '(x: string | number) => number'.
    Types of parameters 'x' and 'x' are incompatible.
      Type 'string | number' is not assignable to type 'number'.
        Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'.
```

Instead, I get a console output of "dupa".

I tried changing types (X, Y) = (number, string) to other pairs, assuming that some implicit casting may be performed. But I get the same effect with other types, like arbitrary, non-assignable types X and Y, or even some X and Y=null (I work with strictNullChecks).

Also, I am capable of generating type error `Type 'string | number' is not assignable to type 'number'.   Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'.` So in general such assignment is not legal.

As noted below, it seems that "it is a feature not a bug", see
https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/22156

Thus, I would like to reformulate the question:

Is there a workaround, which forces the type checker of TypeScript to detect such lack of contravariance in parameter types of overriden methods?

Comment: Which part are you expecting to give an error? The part where you write `override do(x: number): number`, or the part where you call `.do("dupa")`? By the way, `(<A>new B())` says to typescript "Ignore the types, and assume this is an A". This has no effect at runtime, it just silences typescript at compile time.

Comment: I expect the part `override do(x: number):number` to produce an error. The code below is just to illustrate what can happen. I edited the code to emphasise the problem.

Comment: What design are you trying to model? Maybe composition and/or generics would fit better than inheritance?

Comment: The question is not about code - the code is just a plain class hierarchy. I want to be forced to declare the type of `x` in `B.do(x)` as `number | string`. Today I found a bug in my code caused by some overriding method in a subclass having too narrow parameter type. And I'm unhappy about it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order for TypeScript to be truly [sound](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html#a-note-on-soundness) or type-safe, it would need to compare all function and method parameters *contravariantly* so that method overrides could only widen but not narrow the parameter types. (See [Difference between Variance, Covariance, Contravariance and Bivariance in TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66410115/2887218) for more discussion of variance.)

But TypeScript is not truly sound, nor is it intended to be; see [TypeScript Design Non Goal](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/TypeScript-Design-Goals#non-goals) #3, where it says that it is *not* a goal to "apply a sound or 'provably correct' type system" and that the actual goal is to "strike a balance between correctness and productivity."

In TypeScript method parameters are actually [compared *bivariantly*](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html#function-parameter-bivariance), so you are allowed to both widen *and* narrow parameter types when overriding methods.  Originally this was true of all function types, but the introduction of [the `--strictFunctionTypes`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-6.html#strict-function-types) compiler option made non-method function types strict.  But with or without that option enabled, method parameters are still compared bivariantly.

This is for several reasons. [One reason](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-are-function-parameters-bivariant) is that most developers want to treat `Array<T>` as being covariant in `T`, so an `Array<Dog>` is also an `Array<Animal>`:

```
interface Animal { move(): void; }
interface Dog extends Animal { bark(): void; }
const dogs: Dog[] = [];
const animals: Animal[] = dogs; // okay
animals.forEach(a => a.move()); // okay
```

This is unsound because if you `push()` a `Cat` onto an `Array<Animal>` which is actually an alias to an `Array<Dog>`, you've broken things:

```
interface Cat extends Animal { meow(): void; }
const cat: Cat = { move() { }, meow() { } };
animals.push(cat); // okay
dogs.forEach(d => d.bark()) // ERROR AT RUNTIME
```

But such unsoundness is already part of the way TypeScript works with properties.  Properties are covariant even though you can write to them, so the same thing happens even without arrays:

```
const dog: Dog = { move() { }, bark() { } };
const dogCage = { resident: dog };
const animalCage: { resident: Animal } = dogCage; // okay
animalCage.resident = cat; // switcharoo
dogCage.resident.bark(); // ERROR AT RUNTIME AGAIN
```

So forcing methods to be sound when properties aren't is sort of "too little, too late" for the type system.  One could tighten things up by forcing properties to be invariant, or only allowing covariance on `readonly` properties, etc., but this turns out to be very annoying for the vast majority of use cases where people do the right thing.

Still, they were considering enforcing this for methods with `--strictFunctionTypes`.  But unfortunately, [according to the documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#strictFunctionTypes), "during development of this feature, we discovered a large number of inherently unsafe class hierarchies, including some in the DOM."  So some existing native JavaScript `class` hierarchies violate this rule, and enforcing it would put TypeScript in the unfortunate position of invalidating native JavaScript in some way.

Rather than do this, they made the pragmatic decision to keep allowing unsafe method overrides, while prohibiting unsafe standalone functions and callback function types.

---

So if you need a workaround, you could refactor your code to use function-valued properties instead of methods, at least syntactically in your type definitions.  For example:

```
interface A {
    do: (x: number | string) => number;
}

class B implements A {
    do(x: number): number { // error!
        return x;
    }
}
```

Here I've turned `A` into an `interface` because you're not allowed to override a `class`'s function-valued property with a method, even if it's `abstract` (see [microsoft/TypeScript#51261](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/51261)).  If you need the parent to be a class you could possibly just use function-valued properties instead of methods, although these change whether they exist on instances or the prototype:

```
abstract class A {
    abstract do: (x: number | string) => number;
}

class B extends A {
    override do = function (x: number) { // error            
        return x;
    }
}
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=9#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgIImAWzgG2Qb2UwHsA3CACgEoAuZU44AEwG5kBfAKFElkRQAixAObIIAD0ggmAZzQZseQgCM4UANbU6DZmy49o8JMgDCcMGMkRpc9FlwEiEYgHct9Rqw6cExEDIsmERk6IWEAbQBdZABeZCiWHz8A5DgFXBD5exwo2OQg4Rk2AHpi5GJ1OABPTjTsmQA6GGIoAFFEAAsKOFiAPlSGknJqKhKyiuqk-wsEczozCzjCIcoqR3YAGidXanWORLrFRoAHAFcZLtmwUeRS8sqasCgqgk5kd-zgppb2hC6mPr5BqqDQjW5lVoAJUhAHlIWgACrISEAVQAcgiAJIAWVanHYyCuf2QFAga0Ivn8xBwEAaOBEpLWXCmKQKoREeWWZFW6y2IM05I4+xZgREZmEKCWyCgEBkzGsYDoBWFlJSh1w4ogdEIMrlTAVdDsiiFcQKmrG90m6pwmoauvl4DyVwtMhcwDAfzUxGInDNcAldtlDrAwLUAotUNh8NQSNRGJxrTQAHFUJi0ZwMwY+MZUK8Pp86BRxHQQKdMMpoMgAD7IAJQUDCNYxfql8vQRLMhA4OAyOQAIWQWGONMwCtseY+QSLJbLFagtGQrbnjju0CgLQAhG98x8ZWBTlAQMhxIl81xmSA4KOZMd+MgYVBXtv3nBlHXEDNu720BOd6k308H4FiSxaLrOlY1nWDZNi24FQKeHzMvmXY9v2lhSLIP74M+O7clA9b6p8eQwKcIAIGAwB+CBM5tvOK5lGuLR-n+OHMdKED7oex4IX+XBnhm7BAA)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that "it's a feature not a bug", as explained here:

https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/22156

I'm very sad: it means that even with all the strict flags (strict, strictFunctionTypes) you can have an error-free code that just doesn't work due to a type error.

Comment: "Or maybe there is some work around?" Are you asking a new question inside of an answer? That's not really how SO is supposed to work.  If you want to fold this into your original question you should edit it to ask that one.  I'd be happy to write up a separate answer about TS method bivariance and point to [this possible workaround](https://tsplay.dev/w6pVrm) where you use a function-valued property type instead of a method.  How would you like to proceed?  (Also: do note that `--alwaysStrict` has nothing to do with TS type checking; it just means `"use strict"` is output in the JS.)

Comment: Thanks for your comment and interest. I edited the question and the answer to obey the customs of SO. Thanks for the example! I will be grateful if you wrote a longer explanation of the difference between the fields and methods. I'll gladly learn what would be the suggested way of coding and what is the source reason of the issue.