# Understanding the inheritance hierarchy of Tuple2 class in Scala 3.3.1

Tags: scala, inheritance, tuples, scala-3

I'd like more clarity in understanding the place [Tuple2 class in Scala 3.3.1](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/3.3.1/scala/Tuple2.html).

[In its source code](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.13.10/src/library/scala/Tuple2.scala), what is clear is that this class inherits the Product2 trait. What remains doubt to me is how it comes into being that Tuple2 also inherits immediately from:

- class T1 *: T2 *: EmptyTuple.type
- trait Serializable

I haven't been able understood that.

I've read through relevant Scala doc and source code. I can understand the overall design idea of inheritance of these hierarchy but I haven't understood the more nuanced points (the question as an example)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's not confuse classes and types, inheritance (subclassing) and subtyping

[What is the difference between Type and Class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/468145/what-is-the-difference-between-type-and-class)

[What is the difference between a class and a type in Scala (and Java)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5031640/what-is-the-difference-between-a-class-and-a-type-in-scala-and-java)

https://typelevel.org/blog/2017/02/13/more-types-than-classes.html

[What is the difference between subtyping and inheritance in OO programming?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23592131/what-is-the-difference-between-subtyping-and-inheritance-in-oo-programming)

https://counterexamples.org/subtyping-vs-inheritance.html

From OOP point of view, `Tuple2` extends (is a **subclass** of) `Product2`, `Product2` extends `Product`. And `*:` extends `NonEmptyTuple`, `NonEmptyTuple` and `EmptyTuple` extend `Tuple`. Two independent OOP hierarchies.

Making `A *: B *: EmptyTuple` a **subtype** of `Tuple2[A, B]` and vice versa (and providing syntax sugar `(A, B)`) is a compiler magic. According to the spec,

> A tuple type `(T1,...,Tn)` where `n ≥ 2` is sugar for the type `T1 *: ... *: Tn *: scala.EmptyTuple`, which is itself a series of nested infix types which are sugar for `*:[T1​, *:[T2​, ... *:[Tn​, scala.EmptyTuple]]]`.

https://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/3.4/03-types.html#tuple-types

> The conformance relation `(<:)` is the smallest relation such that `S <: T` is true if any of the following conditions hold.
>
> - ...
> - `T = scala.Tuple_n​[T1​,...,Tn​]` with `1 ≤ n ≤ 22`, and `S <: T1​ *: ... *: Tn​ *: scala.EmptyTuple`.

https://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/3.4/03-types.html#conformance

In the compiler, subtyping is implemented in `TypeComparer`

```scala
  /** Does `tycon` have a field with type `tparam`? Special cased for `scala.*:`
   *  as that type is artificially added to tuples. */
  private def typeparamCorrespondsToField(tycon: Type, tparam: TypeParamInfo): Boolean = ...
```

```scala
    /** Subtype test for the hk application `tp2 = tycon2[args2]`.
     */
    def compareAppliedType2(tp2: AppliedType, tycon2: Type, args2: List[Type]): Boolean = {
      ...
        case tycon2: TypeRef =>
          ...
            tycon2.info match {
              ...
              case info2: ClassInfo =>
                tycon2.name.startsWith("Tuple") &&
                  defn.isTupleNType(tp2) && recur(tp1, tp2.toNestedPairs) ||
                tryBaseType(info2.cls)
```

https://dotty.epfl.ch/docs/internals/type-system.html#subtyping-checks-1

https://github.com/lampepfl/dotty/blob/main/compiler/src/dotty/tools/dotc/core/TypeComparer.scala

Regarding `Serializable`, all case classes extend `Product` and `Serializable` and `Tuple2` is a case class. You can switch on `scalacOptions ++= Seq("-Vprint:typer", "-Xprint-types"`) and see

```scala
case class MyClass(i: Int, s: String)

//    case class MyClass(i: Int, s: String) extends
//      <<<new Object:Object>:((): Object)>():Object>, Product, Serializable {
//      ...
```

Here is explanation of generating sugar for case classes in Scala 2 but in Scala 3 this should be similar

[How can I view the code that Scala uses to automatically generate the apply function for case classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60999247/how-can-i-view-the-code-that-scala-uses-to-automatically-generate-the-apply-func)

(so one can find a specific place where `extends Serializable` is added).